# sidekiq suddenly stops working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, bigdecimal, activesupport

I'm using `sidekiq` to run background processes in a rails application.
It was working fine since yesterday, but now when i try to run it with `sidekiq` in a command line interface I get

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1.0.5, ~> 1.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::BASE
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_ALL
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_NaN
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_INFINITY
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_UNDERFLOW
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_OVERFLOW
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::EXCEPTION_ZERODIVIDE
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_MODE
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_UP
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_DOWN
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_UP
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_DOWN
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_CEILING
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_FLOOR
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_EVEN
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NaN
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_POSITIVE_ZERO
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NEGATIVE_ZERO
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_POSITIVE_FINITE
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NEGATIVE_FINITE
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_POSITIVE_INFINITE
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::SIGN_NEGATIVE_INFINITE
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::INFINITY
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/armv6l-linux-eabihf/bigdecimal.so: warning: already initialized constant BigDecimal::NAN
2015-08-17T13:50:43.622Z 1730 TID-5eckc INFO: Booting Sidekiq 3.4.2 with redis options {:url=>"redis://localhost:6379/3", :namespace=>"s
idekiq"}
undefined method `add_builtin_type' for Psych:Module
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `block in eager_load!'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `each_value'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `eager_load!'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support.rb:69:in `eager_load!'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/roberto/web/boardInterface/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:241:in `require'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:241:in `boot_system'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:50:in `run'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.2/bin/sidekiq:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/home/roberto/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
```

I do have `redis-server` running in port 6379.
I've tried to `gem update`, but it changes nothing.
Removing the gem `bigdecimal` gets rid of the `already initialized` warnings, but the `undefined method` error persists and causes `sidekiq` to crash.
Googling it yielded no useful results from what I've found in a day of researches.
Thanks in advance.

### Software in use

**uname -a**

```
Linux PiServer 4.0.8-2-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Tue Jul 14 18:45:50 MDT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

**ruby --version**

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [armv6l-linux-eabihf]
```

**rails --version**

```
Rails 4.2.3
```

**sidekiq --version**

```
Sidekiq 3.4.2
```

**gem list --local | grep psych**

```
psych (2.0.13, 2.0.8)
```

### Hardware in use

```
Raspberry pi model B+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following steps:

- Remove current version of ruby along with all libraries, gems and files that depend on it.
- Install ruby via [RVM](https://rvm.io). It takes a lifetime to compile on the RPi but *might* help avoid the `BigDecimal` error.
- In your project `require 'grape'` according to [issue #181 on GitHub](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/181), *might* help with the `add_builtin_type` error.

I can't reproduce the error on my Πs.